# How to handle too many QML and audio files

Tags: qt, qml, gstreamer

I finished a Qt Quick UI project, where I am using many QML and audio files. It is an application for children. In the main screen I have 10 sections. One is for letters (Pismena.qml), second for numbers(Cislice.qml) etc (Tvary.qml,Farby.qml). If you choose some section, then you can browse through the images, which are accompanied by sound. One section contains about 30 png and 30 mp3 files. Everything works fine.

But if I want to deploy this application and transform this project into a Qt Quick Application project, I have a problem. For three sections it is OK, but if I want to use four sections, I get errors like:

> ```
> Error: "Internal data flow error."
> ```

> ```
> Error: "GStreamer encountered a general stream error."
> ```

> ```
> Error: "Failed to connect stream: Too large"
> ```

These error messages are displayed immediately when I start the application, not when I am browsing the images. 
Also some audio elements are not played.

Here is my **main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("applicationDirPath", QGuiApplication::applicationDirPath());
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is my **main.qml** (it's not complete)

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1024
    height:300

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        id: appWindow
        property alias pismenaIconAlias: pismenaIcon

        Pismena{
            id: pismena
            visible: false
        }    

        Cislice{
            id: cislice
            visible: false
        }

        Farby{
            id: farby
            visible: false
        }

        Tvary{
            id: tvary
            visible: false
        }

        Image{
            id: pismenaIcon
            source: "file:" + applicationDirPath + "/obrazky/pismenaIcon.png"           
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {
                    parent.visible = false
                    pismena.visible = true

                }                
            }
        }
        Image{
            id: cisliceIcon
            source: "file:" + applicationDirPath + "/obrazky/cisliceIcon.png"
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {
                    parent.visible = false
                    cislice.visible = true                   
            }
        }

        Image{
            id: farbyIcon
            source: "file:" + applicationDirPath + "/obrazky/farbyIcon.png"            
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {                    
                    parent.visible = false
                    farby.visible = true                    
            }
        }

        Image{
            id: tvaryIcon
            source: "file:" + applicationDirPath + "/obrazky/tvaryIcon.png"            
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {                    
                    parent.visible = false
                    tvary.visible = true                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the main.qml file, if you choose Pismena(pismenaIcon Image element), you are redirected to that file - **Pismena.qml**, where you can browse through Images with sounds:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import "myJava.js" as MyScript
import QtMultimedia 5.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
Item {
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
    Audio {
        id: hrajPismeno

    }
    Image {
        id: pis     
        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                pis.source = "file:" + applicationDirPath + MyScript.cobr()
                hrajPismeno.source = "file:" + applicationDirPath + MyScript.zobr()
                hrajPismeno.play()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my **myJava.js**

```
.pragma library
var pr = 0;
var c = 1;
var z = 1;
var numberOfItems = 33;
var itemFolder = "\/pismena\/";
function cobr(){
    c = (c === numberOfItems) ? 0 : c;
    c = c + 1;
    var s = itemFolder + c + ".png";
    return s;
}
function setLetters(){
    numberOfItems = 33;
    itemFolder = "\/pismena\/";
}
function zobr(){
    z = (z === numberOfItems) ? 0 : z;
    z = z + 1;
    var r = itemFolder + z + ".mp3";
    return r;
}
```

I am using Qt 5.3 On Linux Mint 13.

Why I can not use many Audio files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Pismena.qml` you have not set the initial `width` and `height` for the `Item` and also for the `Image`. So in the window there is no place where user can actually click. Also there is no default path for the `Image` element.

**EDIT**

In each `Audio` element, set the `autoLoad` property to `false`.

Comment: In original Pismena.qml I have for Item width: parent.width height: parent.height and for Image it is  height: 0.4*appWindow.height/(720/sourceSize.height)
            width: 0.4*appWindow.height/(720/sourceSize.height)*sourceSize.width/sourceSize.height
But I didn't put it here, because original is too long, and I think it is not so importent. Sorry.

Comment: Then you should use debugger. Put `console.log("Image clicked")` in `onClicked`. Put `console.log(hrajPismeno.errorString)` after `hrajPismeno.play` and try to see where error is coming.

Comment: I forget to mention one thing. I am sorry. My error messages are displayed immediately when I start the application, not when I am browsing the images. Anyway I tried yout advice, but there is no error message in place of  console.log(hrajPismeno.errorString)

Comment: I think it's a bug in the system. Have you compiled the code on any other platform ?

Comment: I also tried that on Mint 17.2 with the same result.

Comment: Then it might be a bug in the Qt SDK. A bug existed in previous version, but now it's closed. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-24937
If you application is open source I can give a look.

Comment: My application is open source. I think it would be great if you could look at it. My email is vmskoupil@gmail.com. Please contact me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: EDIT is great solution for my answer. Lot of thanks.